# Is Traffic control inside namespace on ports created by OpenvSwitch supported?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, tc, namespace

I am trying to limit the bandwidth of an interface inside a namespace using tc without much success. Seems it's not supported according to https://lists.linux-foundation.org/pipermail/containers/2009-September/020473.html

This is on CentOS 6.5. What's weird is when I use the tutorial outlind here it works normally: http://gigawhitlocks.com/2014/08/18/network-namespaces.html So it must be something special that's happening to this port created by Openstack inside the namespace. The port that's not working is a port serving as gateway for a virtual router inside openstack.

Edit2: Some more info about the interface which doesn't work with tc:
`ip netns exec qrouter-6a080f37.. ethtool -S qr-a9b3962f-d4
no stats available`

Edit: Seems somebody else is encountering the same problem with ports created by openvswitch in a namespace http://openvswitch.org/pipermail/discuss/2014-May/013925.html

The following command just fails with RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument:

```
# ip netns exec qrouter-6a080f37-4da0-4646-ad36-062b748d15be tc qdisc add dev qr-a9b3962f-d4 root netem loss 30%
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
[root@node-1 ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-6a080f37-4da0-4646-ad36-062b748d15be ip a
43: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
44: qg-4bda7108-d2: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether fa:16:3e:95:cc:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 119.81.159.206/27 brd 119.81.159.223 scope global qg-4bda7108-d2
    inet 119.81.159.207/32 brd 119.81.159.207 scope global qg-4bda7108-d2
    inet 119.81.159.209/32 brd 119.81.159.209 scope global qg-4bda7108-d2
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe95:cc7b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
47: qr-a9b3962f-d4: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether fa:16:3e:c2:64:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.99.1/24 brd 192.168.99.255 scope global qr-a9b3962f-d4
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fec2:64dd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
# ip netns exec qrouter-6a080f37-4da0-4646-ad36-062b748d15be tc qdisc add dev qr-a9b3962f-d4 root tbf rate 1mbit burst 10kb limit 100kb
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem. It does not report error as your qdisc command did when I add qdisc to the internal qr- port, however the traffic just wouldn't be throttled and went at line rate all the time. Googled a while and can not find solution. An ugly way to throttle traffic is to use iptable's limit module, which is impossible to get stable rate on tcp flow, and hard to translate the limit argument to actual bandwidth.